# C# Method to sum hh:mm data ???

Tags: c#, datetime, time, timespan, date-math

I want a method that will sum data that is string in the format hh:mm (time hours and minutes)

0:15 + 0:15 = 0:30

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Convert the strings to `TimeSpan`s and then call the `.Add` method.

```
TimeSpan s1 = TimeSpan.Parse("0:15");
TimeSpan s2 = TimeSpan.Parse("0:45");

TimeSpan s3 = s1 + s2;

// not tested; should work.
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx